# Why is the $A \cap C$ not closed in $C$ in the below setting?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a first countable topological space, $A \subset X$ not closed and $x \in \overline{A} - A$. As $X$ is first countable, there exists a sequence $\{x_n ; n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset A$ converging to $x$. Now let $C := \{ x \} \cup \{x_n ; n \in \mathbb{N} \} $. Why is the $A \cap C$ not closed in $C$?

Comment: Because x is not in A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in C$ is a limitpoint of $A\cap C=\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}\subset C$ but is not an element of $A\cap C$.

So $A\cap C$ does not contain all its limitpoints in $C$. Then it is not closed.

Comment: You're using that all limitpoints of a sequence in $C$ are contained in the closure of $C$, right?

Comment: I am not speaking of [limitpoints of a *sequence*](http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/real-analysis/limit-points-of-a-sequence.html) but of [limitpoints of a *set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point). I am using that a set is closed if and only if it contains all its limitpoints.

Comment: Ah okay, I am not familiar with that concept actually. But the argument also works with limitpoints of a sequence, doesn't it?

Comment: In a first countable topological topological space $x$ is a limitpoint of set $B$ if and only if there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $B$ such that $x=\lim x_n$ and $x_n\neq x$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is not closed $\overline A\setminus A\neq \emptyset$. Consider $x\in \overline A\setminus A$ and $U\subset X$ open such that $x\in U$. Then $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$.

Now $U\cap C$ is open in $C$ with $x\in U\cap C$ but $(U\cap C)\cap A=U\cap A\neq\emptyset$.

This works for arbitrary open $U$ with $x\in U$, so $C\setminus A$ is not open in $C$ hence $A$ is not closed in $C$.

Comment: I don't understand some steps: 1. why $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$? 2. Why is $ C - A$ not open in C then?

Comment: 1.I'm familiar with the definition $\overline A:=\{x\in X~:~U\cap A\neq\emptyset \forall U\text{ neighbourhood of }x\}$. Since $x\in\overline A$ use the definition. 2. $x\in C\setminus A$ but each open neighbourhood of $x$ in $C$ intersects $A$ not empty, hence $C\setminus A$ is not open.